# Back colors and images not printing in ms access 2016

Tags: ms-access, printing, report

I have a problem in an already developed ms access application that was working fine till access 2010.
After upgrade to access 2016 I have my reports not printing back colors of controls and images when printing to specific printer.
When changing the printer it works fine. I tried to print to the printer from other applications it was working fine. It seems something specific to this printer with access 2016 that I can't identify.
I created new database file with a simple report with control back color and image and problem is still the same.
In all cases the preview works normal but problem only when printing to my main printer (HP MFP400 laser).
Any checks or suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, update the printer driver, or use another (old) driver of Windows, for example for LaserJet II or IV or a Xerox or Apple PostScript driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***@Gustav Thanks a lot for your suggestion.
I replaced the driver with Xerox PostScript driver as you suggested and it worked fine. Problem Solved***

> *If you haven't already done so, update the printer driver, or use another (old) driver of Windows, for example for LaserJet II or IV or a Xerox or Apple PostScript driver. – Gustav Aug 29 at 16:00*